# QT - Understanding following lambda expression for a SLOT

Tags: qt

I am currently trying to understand the new QT5 signal/slot syntax

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged, [=](const QString &newValue) {
       receiver->updateValue("senderValue", newValue);
   });
```

Now my question is where is the address of the receiver SLOT in the above expression ? I wanted to know this because what happens if a signal is in threadA and the slot is in thread B and I wanted it to be a queued connection ?

Answer (score 7):

A slot is a piece of code, it doesn't "live" in a thread - a thread might run it or not, but the code itself doesn't belong to any thread. (If the slot is a member function, then the Qt object defined as the receiver belongs to a Qt thread - that's a property of the object, not the function.)

In the code you have above, the compiler generates an object that:

- captures `receiver` by value (`[=]`)
- has a function-call operator that can be called with a reference to a const QString.

That object is passed to `connect` along with the other two arguments. It's not a `QObject`, so it doesn't have an owning thread in the Qt sense. What you need to make sure of is that:

- what `receiver` points to stays alive for as long as that signal is connected
- `receiver->updateValue(...)` is thread-safe - it will be called in `sender`'s context/thread.

If `receiver->updateValue` needs to be called in `receiver`'s thread/context, then do not use that syntax for the `connect` call, use the one where you specify both sender and receiver, and the connection type.

Comment: Note: to allow deletion of receiver, wrapping the pointer in closure in `QPointer` should do it.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your statement "it doesn't "live" in a thread - a thread might run it or not, but the code itself doesn't belong to any thread" could you explain this a little. Say I have a main thread and a secondary thread. If the slot is declared in the secondary thread it wont be able to update the GUI. Am I correct ? The slot needs to be on the main GuI thread for it to update the GUI

Comment: QObject intances (i.e. data) belong to QThreads. Functions (member functions or not) don't belong to threads. Slots don't belong to threads - they are functions. The sender of a signal, and the receiver _if_ it's a QObject do belong to QThreads. In the case you have, the receiver is not a QObject, its an instance of a plain C++ class - it doesn't belong to any QThread.

Comment: In other words: the lambda function will be executed in the thread that raises the signal. If you don't want that, you'll have to specify a receiver QObject whose event queue runs in the desired thread - a GUI object in MistyD's case. (Which I did. Thanks!)